# JQuery closest() help

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle, slide

So I have several containers with this markup on a page:

```
        <div class="box w400">
            <div class="box-header">
                <span class="expand-collapse">expand/collapse</span>
                <h3>Heading</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="box-content">
                <p>Some content here...</p>
            </div>
        </div>
```

And I am trying to achieve that after clicking on the .expand-collapse span, the .box-content div will slide up or down (toggle).

Here is the jQuery I'm using, I am trying to achieve this with closest():

```
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.expand-collapse').click(function() {
                $(this).closest('.box-content').slideToggle('slow');
            });
        });
```

But it is not working for some reason :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.expand-collapse').click(function() {
        $(this).parent().next('.box-content').slideToggle('slow');
    });
});
```

That selects the next sibling of the parent div, it does not make use of closest.

Answer (score 2):

closest() finds the closes parent element.  In your case, the span doesn't have any parent elements with class .box-content.  why not just do $('.box-content').slideToggle('slow'); ??

edit: i missed the part where you have several of these on a page.  the parent().next should work.

Comment: That will toggle all divs with the class .box-content instead of just the one.

Comment: Because there are several containers on the page and I want each .expand-collapse span to toggle only its .box-content, not all on the page.

Comment: sorry, I reread the post and saw there were several per page.